# A word that sounds like "scoshe" meaning "small amount" or "smidgen"

Tags: single-word-requests

Google and the thesaurus aren't helping, unfortunately.

Comment: Search on "skosh"

Comment: @mfe that's it exactly! You should post that as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that the term comes from the Japanese 'sukoshi' which means a little, or a small amount. As a carpenter in Canada, we used the term a lot and after I moved to Japan and became familiar with the language, it occurred to me one day, that I already knew that particular word.

Comment: World Wide Words [confirms](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-sko1.htm).

Comment: As does the [Straight Dope](http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/1032/whats-the-origin-of-skosh-meaning-a-little-bit).

Comment: +1.  I grew up hearing this in rural Indiana.  Many years later I began studying Japanese.  Years after *that* it occurred to me, "You know, skosh sounds an awful lot like sukoshi!  What a funny coincidence!"  Then, a few months ago, the realization hit me...

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure of the origin, but if you google "skosh" you'll find plenty of stuff. It's one of those words I often describe as "cute farmer talk."